# How to read any data type as bytes?

Tags: python

How to read any data type, whether `int`, `float`, `long`, `complex`, `boolean`, `str`, `set`, `dict`, or any object, byte by byte?

In C, I would read directly from the pointers like:

`unsigned char byte = *(unsigned char *)&x`

Comment: Surprisingly, using `hex`.

Comment: `hex` only takes in integers as argument

Comment: BTW, what do you mean "representation"??? The representation of any object is not affected by what you refer to as "base" (neither in your C example). The base "matters" only when you print it.

Comment: And BTW, your C example doesn't have anything to do with "hex" or "base64" representation (not even for "printing purposes").

Comment: [Docs for hex](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#hex) Notice the note about float being different.

Comment: Edited question for clarification

Comment: Check out the docs for `bytearray`: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray
You could then convert the resulting bytes to hex.

Comment: Yep, that is a lot clearer. I believe that you are essentially looking to "serialize" your data. The output of such operation ("byte by byte") is generally platform-dependent. In your C example, it depends on the Endianness of the underlying HW architecture. In Python, I believe that it depends on the specific implementation of your Python interpreter (though I'm not 100% sure of that).

Comment: @ToxicTeacakes Thanks, this is what I needed.

Comment: @barakmanos does `bytearray` suffer from endianness issues?

Comment: Python doesn't expose (to Python code) the memory used in implementing its builtin data types at the level you're asking about. There's no way to get at the internal implementation of a dictionary or a list without writing your own C extension. Can you clarify what exactly you want this information for? If you're just looking to serialize arbitrary objects, you might want the `pickle` module.

Comment: @Blckknght I'm trying to convert whatever datatype/object to a binary representation and reconstruct it without knowing its initial type. I don't know if that level is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

Using `hex()` function

```
x = 1234
hex(x)
'0x4d2'
```

Comment: Yes, I saw when I refreshed.